# What is needed to design on windows a driver for bluetooth mouse?

Tags: windows, driver

What is needed to design on windows a driver for bluetooth mouse?

Do I need to use .NET framework for that? and do I need to create my own code from scratch is there an existing windows-based api for designers

Comment: Definitely not `.NET`... You are working on the very low-level. This means C/(C++) and a lot of bit-pushing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will definitely need the [`Windows Driver Kit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg487428.aspx) to provide you with the necessary APIs.
And `.NET` won't come in handy there, you will be working with pure C, maybe C++.

Additionally you will need to know about the BT-stack, which is proprietary. Creating Drivers is no piece of cake, definitely. Maybe look for a user-space BT-library.